# Why do group algebras have no semisimiple block?

Tags: representation-theory

Some context: I'm reading chapter X.3 of Representation Theory of Artin Algebras by M.Auslander. A part of this chapter is proving, that representation-finite group algebras are biserial. This is done by proving a more general case for representation-finite algebras stably equivalent to Nakayama algebras. On page 354 an algebra $\Lambda$ is defined to be symmetric with no semisimple block for which Auslander among other things continues to prove, that it is biserial.

Now my actual question: Why does it follow that every representation-finite group algebra is biserial? I have proven that group algebras are symmetric but how can I prove they have no semisimple block? What do we know about the blocks/idempotents of group algebras?

Comment: It is not true that group algebras have no semi-simple block. As a very stupid example, *every* group algebra in characteristic zero is semi-simple. As a slightly less stupid example, the group algebra of the symmetric group $S_3$ over the field with $2$ elements has two blocks, one of which is semi-simple and one of which is not.

Comment: Mhm, that would be unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved it so this is for someone that is asking the same thing.

The no semisimple block part was needed so that no simple modules are projective. But we don't need that to show the group algebra is biserial.

The indecomposable projective modules are just the projective covers of the simple modules.
If $S$ is a projective simple module then $P(S)=S$ and $U=V=\{0\}$ are the uniserial modules we are looking for.

So we only need to look at the non-projective simple modules.